# Сократить условие if

Tags: php

Можно ли как-нибудь сократить условие, чтобы не писать код вручную, а прибавлять цифру автоматически к action_?  Каким нибудь циклом....

```
if($date != $val['action'] && $date != $val['action_2'] && $date != $val['action_3'] && $date != $val['action_4']){
```

Comment: Апочему бы не использовать массив?

Comment: @Qwertiy а как его использовать в данном случае?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать через **[in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php)**

```
if (!in_array($date, ['action1', 'action2', 'action3'])) {

}
```

Comment: цифру ж прибавлять, а не слово. `$actions = array_map($fn($idx) => "action$idx", range(1, $maxN))`